# jquery dhtmlxScheduler disable marked timespans with seprate title

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, dhtmlx-scheduler

I had successfully disabled the times mentioned in zones below code. my problem is all the timespans title shows Appointment Fixed but, I want to show which patient booked the slot in html json.

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({ html: "Appointment Fixed", days: 1, zones: [180, 240,720,840,900,960,1020], css: "red_section", type: "dhx_time_block" });
```

if i give below code am getting error showing parameter constraint error in browser console.

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({ html: ["Patient1","Patient2","Patient3"], days: 1, zones: [180, 240,720,840,900,960], css: "red_section", type: "dhx_time_block" });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

'html' property takes HTML string, not an array. You need to format the timeslot description before passing it to the method, for example

```
scheduler.addMarkedTimespan({ html: "<ul><li>Patient1<li>Patient2<li>Patient3</ul>", days: 1, zones: [180, 240,720,840,900,960], css: "red_section", type: "dhx_time_block" });
```

You may also need to change the line-height setting of timespans in order to allow multiline content.

```
.red_section {
 line-height: 150% !important;
}
```

Comment: @Rajesh , please clarify what exactly have you tried and what did not work... The code from the answer seems working correctly in demos http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/aae1ad91

Comment: @Light Please See this link i want this type...http://docs.dhtmlx.com/scheduler/snippet/71c076f0